# Como funciona .count() c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Este codigo es para contar el numero de vocales que tengo, no se como funciona el metodo .count(), ni los parametros que tiene el count text.count(x => x ==v)

```
        var vocales = new[] { 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'};

        Console.WriteLine("Introduce un texto: ");
        var text = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

        foreach (var v in vocales)
        {

            var matches = text.Count(x => x == v);
            Console.WriteLine($"Existen {matches} vocales {v}");
        }
```

Comment: lo que se utiliza es LINQ, aqui una guia que encontre en internet https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/introduccion-rapida-a-linq-con-c-sharp.aspx

Comment: Es una de las características más elegantes y poderosas del lenguaje C#. Recomiendo encarecidamente lo estudies pues tiene muchísimas aplicaciones y casos de usos. Yo apostaría que te hará la vida más fácil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count es una función del ensamblado System.Linq
Vamos paso por paso:

1.- "vocales" es un array de "char" o sea, que tenemos un arreglo de cada vocal.

2.- El foreach lo que está haciendo es recorrer ese array, primero lo que hace es buscar la letra A, luego la E ... etc etc. La "v"  va a ir tomando el valor de esas vocales cada iteración, la primera iteración esa v = A, la segunda iteración v = B, y así sucesivamente

3.- text.Count(x => x == v) lo que está haciendo es: contar las veces que "v" se encuentra en la palabra que ingresaste, (recuerda que en la primera iteración v = A, entonces si pones "pasta" lo que hará count es contar las veces que la letra "a" aparece en la palabra "pasta", y así lo hará sucesivamente con cada vocal)

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no me queda claro que es lo que se encuentra dentro de los parentesis de .Count()

Comment: Se llama "Expresión Lambda". Es una función que se ejecuta para cada elemento del objeto que lo llama (´texto´, en este caso). La puedes leer de esta manera: Del arreglo `text`, hacer un `count` de los elementos, tal que, el valor del arreglo (**x**) sea igual al valor de **v**. Puedes leer más en la [documentación oficial de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)